# How to collect form atrribute "name" and "value" into array from specific part of form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

how to collect form atrribute "name" and "value" into array from specific part of form using javascript?

I have a part of form like this:

```
<div class="multiPickerForm">
<input type="text" name="Id" value="1">
<input type="text" name="OrderNumber" value="SK4569">
<span class="multiPickerItemAddBtn"></span>
</div>
```

i need to read that part of form using javascript and create array of objects like.

```
var obj = { name:'OrderNumber', value:'SK4569' }
```

or something like that so i could loop it and access data easily from formated objects for further development.

Any advice would be highly apreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
var obj = [];
$("div.multiPickerForm :input").each(function () {
  var tmpPair new Object();
  tmpPair['name'] = $(this).attr('name');
  tmpPair['value'] =  = $(this).val();
  obj.push(tmpPair);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What about other form controls, like selects, checkboxes, radio buttons, and so on? Presumably the OP only wants sucessful controls.

Comment: I've updated the selector to use :input rather than simply input to get other field types, such as select and textarea.  If he needs to only select those which are "active" (a need he didn't mention) then he will have to add some :checked or :selected logic in there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)  and it does exactly what you need

```
<div class="multiPickerForm">
 <input type="text" name="Id" value="1">
 <input type="text" name="OrderNumber" value="SK4569">
 <span class="multiPickerItemAddBtn">        </span>
  </div>

$('.multiPickerForm :input').serializeArray()
```

EDIT - You can use it on a form or on a subset of form elements, i updated my example. Taken from the documentation

> This method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form elements, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`. However, it
>   is typically easier to select the  tag itself for serialization:

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/yffr5/

Comment: But he said he only wants "part" of a form.

Comment: @JakeFeasel sorry, i modified my answer to use serializeArray on a subset of elements

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yffr5/1/ I suggest updating to use :input selector, as I have made on your fiddle here

Comment: @JakeFeasel yes you are right, it's too early in the morning and i didn't see the select!!!

Comment: Well... to be fair, the select was something I added to test it.  So you didn't really miss it :)

Answer (score 0):

The controls in a form can be accessed using the [elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-76728479) collection. You can iterate over them to test if they are descendents of a div with class *multiPickerForm*.

If they are and they are sucessful, put them in the array as an object.